# Is there mouse acceleration in MW3?  If so, how can I disable it?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, mouse

Mouse acceleration (also called "Enhance pointer precision") is a feature in which the distanced moved by the on-screen pointer is not simply proportional to the distanced moved by the mouse. Instead, it also takes mouse speed into account.

I have mouse acceleration disabled in my Windows 7, but I'm under the impression that this effect is still happening as I play *Modern Warfare 3*. **Does anyone know if the game implements its own version of mouse acceleration? If so, how can I disable it?**

The "Smooth Mouse" option is also already disabled for me.

Comment: Is there any other DirectX game you can verify against? I have turned it in WIndows off (registry hack) and I don't feel any acceleration going on in MW3.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the mouse sensitivity settings from the options screen?

Comment: @IanPugsley Bora, There have been several moments when my vision turns almost 180° around in middle of a heated combat. It could have been just performance lags or somethings. That's why I'm asking after all. =)

Comment: @BruceConnor - I'm saying you should be able to reduce your mouse sensitivity from the options menu, and it should alter that behavior.

Comment: @IanPugsley Isn't mouse sensitivity just the proportion between mouse speed and pointer speed? Changing its value shouldn't affect mouse accel, which actually makes the two speeds *not* proportional.

Comment: To my knowledge MW3 doesn't specifically perform any mouse acceleration (and it isn't configurable) - but if you're seeing full 180° turns, changing your sensitivity a bit might help (unless you're satisfied with it when not moving the mouse quickly).  Additionally, I've seen some mention of people solving mouse accel issues by shutting off mouse-specific software from the manufacturer (Logitech, Microsoft, Razer, etc.).  Also try a lower polling rate if your mouse supports it.

Comment: If you have any applications in the background while the game is running they might cuase short freezes causing the game to register mouse movements in real time. When it would catch up, you might have then turned 180°.

Comment: @Bora This seems to be the best possibility. I'm almost convinced I'm getting short performance lags/freezes which are causing the mouse to misbehave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is an acceleration setting, it's in the line: `seta cl_mouseAccel "0"`
in the config file, stored in:
`\Steam\steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 3\players2`
(if you don't use Steam, the route will be different, of course)

That didn't work for me, since it was already set to 0. This is what did the trick:
With the game running, Task Manager -> Details -> iw3mp.exe -> set priority -> normal.

I have a considerable level of knowledge about how an Operating System works, and I can only vaguely guess why this is happening.

[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2236848)

Comment: Surprisingly changing priority from High to Normal works! Can anybody explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well, and I found out that this is more to do with CPU/GPU delay than the mouse acceleration issue.  Try lowering your polling rate for your mouse, as well as disable any mouse specific software that's running in the background (Razer, logitech and etc's configuration programs).  That fixed it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable "Enhance pointer precision" in the Mouse -> Pointer Options